# Making CKAN Postgres DB permanent on Cloud

Tags: ckan

We're working on deploying CKAN on Cloud using [this docker-compose network](https://github.com/okfn/docker-ckan). We're not storing any datasets but only publish URLs to data resources. We would like to stand up a permanent Postgres database on Cloud (AWS) to replace the `db` service, but it's not clear to me how this can be done. For example, how can we point to the db endpoint, having only db name, user and password editable in [Dockerfile](https://github.com/okfn/docker-ckan/blob/master/postgresql/Dockerfile)? How Docker volumes come into play here?

So far, I created on AWS an RDS instance with 4 databases (ckan, ckan_test, datastore and datastore_test) and 2 users (ckan and datastore_ro) with the former having read and write access to all the databases while datastore_ro has only read access to datastore* databases. I updated the env vars accordingly. But I still don't understand if this would entirely replace the `db` service or they're two completely different components?

Pointers to any helpful documentation will be appreciated!